# Object definition in the canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I'm making a final project in my last year of college called "Data Flow Diagram Drawing Tool" which is website based. I am having difficulties on how to make a warning when the diagram in the canvas is wrong. For example, a Terminator meets Data Flow THEN meets Process is correct. But when a Terminator meets Data Flow AND THEN meets Storage is wrong. How can I make a warning when this mistake occurred? Obviously I need some kind of object definition for each shape in the canvas. How do I do that? I really need help :(

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a quick outline of how to create and validate your data-flow steps:**

- Create JavaScript objects to hold the information related to each step in your data-flow diagram.
- Save all the step-objects in an array for easy processing
- Iterate through the steps array and validate each step.

**Example code:**

```
// create javascript objects representing data-flow steps
// and put the steps objects in an array for easy processing
var steps=[];
steps.push({type:'External',label:'Customer'});
steps.push({type:'Flow',label:'Place Order',isBidirectional:true});
steps.push({type:'Process',label:'Process Order'});
steps.push({type:'Flow',label:'Save Order',isBidirectional:false});
steps.push({type:'Storage',label:'DB Table: Orders'});

// start out assuming all steps are valid
for(var i=1;i<steps;i++){ steps[i].isValid=true; }

// look for invalid steps and mark them
// This example checks for sequential steps not separated by flows
for(var i=1;i<steps;i++){
    if(steps[i-1].type!=='Flow' && steps[i].type!=='Flow){
        steps[i].isValid=false;
    }
}
```